# Flutter : Future inside another Future

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

In my flutter app I have some nested `Future` jobs to perform. For an example, I first need to the current user's email from Firebase and then based on the email I get, pull the correct user from the database.

This I have implemented in below

```
class LoadSellAdsUIState extends State<LoadSellAdsUI> {
  FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
  User user;
  bool startUILoad=false;


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    Future.wait([
      FirebaseJobs.getCurrentUser().then((firebaseUserTemp) {
        if (firebaseUserTemp != null) {
          firebaseUser = firebaseUserTemp;

          DataFetch()
              .loadUser(AppNavigation.getAPIUrl() +"user/getUserByEmail/" +firebaseUser.email)
              .then((User userTemp) {

                if(user!=null)
                {
                    user = userTemp;
                    print(user.email + " : " + user.iduser.toString());
                }

              setState(() {
                startUILoad=true;
              });

          });
        }
      })
    ]);
  }
//other code here
}
```

My `Future`s are defined in another class, below are the code of the above mentioned `Future`s

```
static final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

static Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser()
  {
    return _auth.currentUser();

  }

Future<User> loadUser(String url) async {
    final response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return User.fromJson(convert.json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
```

Please note I am using the `Future` inside an `initState` method.

The issue is the code never waits for the inner `Future` (`DataFetch().loadUser()`)) and it always move to the `build` method.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: what do you need `Future.wait` for? simply use `FirebaseJobs.getCurrentUser().then(...)`

Comment: @pskink: I noticed that without that, even the code do not stop for the first `Future` !

Comment: so is `FirebaseJobs.getCurrentUser().then(...)` fired? i mean `then(...)`

Comment: @pskink: Without `Future.wait` ? Yes, but after the UI is loaded and exceptions are thrown by the UI because it has no data to work on.

Comment: exceptions? what exceptions? this one: `throw Exception('Failed to load post');`?

Comment: @pskink: null exceptions. email is null, userID is null and so on. Those are the data I collect by these `Future`s

Comment: ok i still have no itea what you want to achieve with `Future.wait` - if you want to chain some `Future`s [this](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures#calling-multiple-funcs) is how you do that

Comment: @pskink: As I mentioned, without `Future.wait` the code in `initState` do not wait for it to complete. Instead it moves on into `build` method, while the `Future`s are still performing. Somehow `Future.wait` managed to stop it for the 1st future.

Comment: it always goes to `build` method - you cannot stop it - instead use `FutureBuilder`

Comment: @pskink: You mean it goes to `build` without waiting for the futures listed in `initState` ?

Comment: Add some `print()` in the beg and the end and watch the logs

Comment: @pskink: I solved the issue just now with a help of a boolean to monitor the state of the`Future`. No I'm serious, in Flutter lifecycle, can `build` be triggered even without waiting for `Future` in `initState` ? I know `initState` will be triggered first, but I am asking about this waiting...

Comment: you dont need any `boolean` - simply use `FutureBuilder` - and yes i am serious too: add this to `initState()` method: `var f0 = Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
  print('this will show after 3 seconds');
  return 33;
});
var f1 = Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
  print('this will show after 5 seconds');
  return 55;
});
print('start of Future.wait');
Future.wait([f0, f1]).then((_) => print('result of Future.wait: $_'));
print('end of Future.wait');`

Comment: so, did you run the code i posted? if so, what did you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue with a help of a boolean to monitor the states of `Future`. The code is below

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();



       //IF THE USER IS NOT LOGGED IN, DIRECT THE USER TO LOGIN
      FirebaseJobs.getCurrentUser().then((firebaseUser){
        if(firebaseUser==null)
        {
          setState(() {
              startUILoad=true;
            });
        }
        else{

          firebaseUser1 = firebaseUser;
          DataFetch().loadUser(AppNavigation.getAPIUrl()+"user/getUserByEmail/"+firebaseUser.email).then((User result)
          {


            user = result;
            setState(() {
              startUILoad=true;
            });
          });
        }
      });


  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return startUILoad? sellAdFutureBuilder() : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
  }
```

Comment: no, you dont need any flag - instead use `FutureBuilder`

Comment: @pskink: FutureBuilder is a `Widget` and it require widget tree to execute. Isn't it?

Comment: `FutureBuilder` is a builder and it builds a widget tree